# Display value of textfield onChange using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is whenever I type a value in the text field, the value typed will be displayed right away.

How do I do it exactly? Is there anyway I could put the value in a variable and use it right away without using onClick?

Comment: No, you must use an event listener. Try the `keyup` event for `<textarea>`s.

Comment: you will always need a trigger but for your case it would be onkeypress

Comment: @RicardoGarzaV. Thank you for enlightening me with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
<script>
function change(){
    var el1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var el2 = document.getElementById("text");
    el1.innerHTML = el2.value;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="text" onkeypress="change()">
<div id="div1"></div>
```

I don't think you can do it without any events.
Maybe you can do it with HTML5's <output> tag. I don't know it very well, but try some research.
W3Schools have some good examples.

Hope this can help you

Comment: What if, say, the question had specified "without using a trigger"?

Comment: Exactly what I needed! God bless you! :D

Comment: @Codemonkey I would edit the question then. What I meant by trigger was by clicking or submitting, etc. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**Without** using the change event? Why on earth would you want this? The only alternative I can think of would be polling at an interval. Something like:

```
var theValue = "";
var theTextBox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');

// Run 10 times per second (every 100ms)
setInterval(function() {
    // Check if the value has changed
    if(theTextBox.value != theValue)
    {
        theValue = theTextBox.value;
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function change(){
var el1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var el2 = document.getElementById("text");
el1.innerHTML = el2.value;
}
function changenew(){
var el1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var el2 = document.getElementById("text");
el1.innerHTML = el2.value;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="text" onkeypress="change()" onchange="changenew()">
```

is it Possible

Answer (score 0):

you can check to see if your input field is in focus, then listen for any [key input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onkeypress) events and update your display field with the appropriate characters.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
​<input type="text" id="myText"/>
<span id="output"></span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

js:

```
var myText = document.getElementById("myText");
myText.onkeyup = function(){
   var output = document.getElementById("output");
   output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/seUBJ/
    ​

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could check two answers!